# What does "where" mean in "Where does Brexit leave Britain?"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, headlinese

I cannot understand the meaning of this sentence.

> Where does Brexit leave Britain?

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brexit), Brexit (like its early variant Brixit), a portmanteau of "Britain" and "exit", is the United Kingdom's withdrawal from the European Union.

In this case, it stands,

> Where does the United Kingdom's withdrawal from the European Union leave Britain?

This makes no sense at all!

Comment: *leave* = place in a final position

Comment: Please give me an answer from valuable and reliable sources.

Comment: @SovereignSun Your question doesn't make clear what you are asking, you merely state that you don't understand one sentence and that another sentence ( which is one you've actually written) makes no sense. if your question is 'what does *where* mean in this context?' you should edit the question to make that clear.

Comment: "Where" is a fronted non-subject here; it functions as a locative complement, cf. "Brexit leaves Britain where"?, in which "where" means in what position or situation. A typical answer might be "better off" or "worse off" or "with greater freedom".

Comment: @JFA I knew the meaning of l*eave*, i was trying to figure out the context meaning of the word *where*

Comment: The answer as approved by the British government is "where means where"

Comment: @JosephRogers Sorry, what?

Comment: Sorry, it's probably not been reported as much abroad, but ever since the vote all the government will say about what's coming our way is "Brexit means Brexit"

Comment: @JosephRogers I am not understanding what you are saying.

Comment: My apologies, it was supposed to be a joke but it's not funny if you don't understand it. Basically, our government has been trying to sound like it knows what it's doing without actually saying anything but continually repeating the line "Brexit means Brexit". This is widely mocked because of course Brexit is a made up word which means nothing at all. Since you were asking about the meaning of a different word in a sentence about Brexit, I thought "where means where" would be funny, but it doesn't work unless you know the back story. You have several good answers from other members.

Comment: @JosephRogers oh, now I get it. Everything is clear.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You seem to have misunderstood the meaning of to *leave*. It means:

> to cause or allow to be or remain in a specified condition

Therefore, the sentence could be understood as meaning:

> Where (In what position, good/bad/awkward/terrible, etc) does Brexit (what you described in the question) leave (cause to be or remain) Britain (object of to *leave*)?

[Merriam-Webster]

Comment: +1. As a non-native, I had trouble with this sentence, you got it right for me. But I'd have used "How" instead of "Where", because it's more a state than a location

Comment: Now it's understandable. It's like: "Where did mom leave the book?" right?Only "where" here doesn't mean "place" but instead it means "condition"

Comment: @Irhala Thanks, *how* and *where* have different meanings, e.g., *how* refers to the process while *where* points to a position as a result of the action (Brexit). The two sentences don't have the same meaning. And if you use *how*, it would mean Brexit is leaving Britain, not the other way around.

Comment: @SovereignSun Yes, that's right. Where could mean many things. Cheers!

Comment: @SovereignSun Most of our words for "state" employ a locative metaphor. Our *situation* is the *site* at which we are located; our *circumstances* are the things *standing around* us; our *position* is where we are *placed*; our *standing* is where we *stand*; and our *state* is where we have been *stood*.

Comment: Even as a native speaker I had trouble parsing the sentence initially.  I wonder if it was a deliberate play on Britain leaving.

Comment: Although this is what 'leave' means in this sentence, there is another meaning, which confusingly was used in the name of one of the Brexit referendum options. There 'Leave' meant the opposite of 'Join'.

Comment: The correct interpretation should most likely be, "In which state does Brexit leave Britain", rather than 'in what position' which is a statement in which 'what' should be 'which' anyway. Colloquially, 'where' can mean 'in which state' where the amount of states are finite but undefined. So, an answer to the question could be, "In a state of anxiety/peace/advanced chaos". Note that where is not defined to mean 'in which state', but it has evolved to include that meaning, because 'in which state' is three words instead of one and is considered rather snooty.

Answer (score 14):

The idiomatic use of the word *leave* is problematic, to be sure! Moreover, the sentence in question is, at best, poorly stated!

Perhaps an illustration would help.

Let's say two guys are bemoaning not having a suit to wear to a special occasion to which they've both been invited. One guy says, "I may not have a suit to wear, but I have a cousin who does, and we're almost exactly the same size. I think I'll ask to borrow his suit!"

The other guy says, "But where does that leave me?"

In other words, the "other guy" is feeling as though he's been left (past tense of leave!) out in the cold without a suit to wear.

Getting back to "Brexit" . . .. The question being asked is "Where, or in what condition, does Britain's exit from the EU leave her?" The word *where* has nothing to do with a literal, physical location; rather, *where* means "in what condition." So, where *is* Britain, having left the EU?

> - out in the cold?
> - isolated?
> - in danger of losing allies?
> - in some other condition, either good, bad, or indifferent?

Britain "leaving" the EU has no semantic connection to exiting; rather, the leaving has to do with a condition Britain might be left in, having exited the EU.

Some other illustrative sentences:

- Your plan is all well and good for you, but where does it leave me?
- Hey, my friend, we're both broke, but you have good credit and I have bad credit. You can go to a bank to get a loan to tide you over, but where does that leave me?
- Jim, I hear you found a date at the last minute for the party tomorrow. That's great, but where does that leave me?

Answer (score 5):

The sentence is intended to be read as, "In what state does Britain's leaving the EU leave it?"  That is, where does Britain go after making such a decision?  Is Britain better or worse off having decided this way or the other? What options are available to Britain now that it's made this decision?

Answer (score 3):

Normally in English, "where" type questions are referencing the relationship between 2 or more physical items and their relative location to each other.  To answer a "where" question, one normally has to provide a second item to serve as a reference point for the location of the first item.

For example:  Where is my TV?

Answers:  On the table.  In my house.  In Texas.  In the US.  On planet earth.  All of the above answers are correct to differing degrees of accuracy.

I think most people's definition of "where" in the above context is easily grasped.

However native English speakers, having fun with our language, will also use "where" to  denote the status of non-physical relationships between non-physical "things".

In the case you mention, Britain while being a physical landmass, is also an non-physical idea, specifically a political organization of people (a nation) who happen to mostly live on the previously mentioned landmass.

The original question being posed is referencing this non-physical idea (the British nation) and is asking in relation to the EU (another non-physical idea, specifically a political alliance of nations) where will the British "stand".  The "standing" is not a physical location, but rather an ideological "location".

Ultimately what is being asked by this question is, will Britain continue to have a constructive relationship with the EU after it ceases to be an active State in the political entity known as the EU.

Other examples that you might commonly see in the English speaking press that conflates physical location and ideological standing:

What nations will fall into the Russian orbit?  Nations won't physically orbit Russia, but if they come under the political influence of the Russian government they will often be referred to as being in the Russian "orbit".

Will the UK and US become closer when the next president takes office?  Again, physically their distance from each other will not change, but if the political goals of each nation become more aligned, then we use the word closer, which is normally related to physical distance, to denote a non-physical comparison in the status of our relationship.

Hope this helps and hope I didn't add to your confusion.

Answer (score 2):

This is very similar to the rhetorical question, "Where do we go from here?" The newspaper is not asking for a location or making travel plans, but rather, it is pondering what will happen to Britain after a majority of its voters chose to leave the EU.